# Oracle Instant Client SDK header files not found

Tags: fedora, oracle-linux

I'm trying to configure phpstorm db plugin to connect to an oracle remote database.

It uses oci8 driver and so I'm going to install it.
(also if I specify to connect using thin driver it connects but then fails querying tables)

As I run

```
sudo pecl install oci8
```

the output stops at this line:

> checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... configure:
>   error: Oracle Instant Client SDK header files not found ERROR:
>   `/var/tmp/oci8/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
>   --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib' failed

I hadn't much luck in finding any clue on this topic.

I just can see that jdk should be installed and the version actually used is the following:

> /etc/alternatives/jre ->
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.fc2

those headers I guess that should be there in the following folder:

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.fc29.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64 -l
total 4996
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Feb  6 19:07 client
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Mar 11 21:42 jli
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    1624 Feb  6 18:22 jvm.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   23872 Feb  6 19:07 libattach.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   55752 Feb  6 19:07 libawt_headless.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  800088 Feb  6 19:07 libawt.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   29768 Feb  6 19:07 libdt_socket.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  494928 Feb  6 19:07 libfontmanager.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  199808 Feb  6 19:07 libhprof.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   66128 Feb  6 19:07 libinstrument.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   57720 Feb  6 19:09 libj2gss.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   23720 Feb  6 19:07 libj2pcsc.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   99200 Feb  6 19:07 libj2pkcs11.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   17296 Feb  6 19:07 libjaas_unix.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   31008 Feb  6 19:07 libjava_crw_demo.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   56688 Feb  6 19:07 libjavajpeg.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  272832 Feb  6 19:07 libjava.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  299640 Feb  6 19:07 libjdwp.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   18248 Feb  6 19:07 libjsdt.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   18016 Feb  6 19:07 libjsig.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   17936 Feb  6 19:07 libjsound.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  523384 Feb  6 19:07 liblcms.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   63200 Feb  6 19:07 libmanagement.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1083880 Feb  6 19:07 libmlib_image.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  134544 Feb  6 19:07 libnet.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  117896 Feb  6 19:07 libnio.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   23272 Feb  6 19:07 libnpt.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   59416 Feb  6 19:07 libsaproc.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   39528 Feb  6 19:07 libsctp.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  158784 Feb  6 19:07 libsunec.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  124648 Feb  6 19:07 libunpack.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   75208 Feb  6 19:07 libverify.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   54712 Feb  6 19:09 libzip.so
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Mar 11 21:43 server
```

I'm running under Fedora29.
`JAVA_HOME`, `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are exported:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.fc29.x86_64/jre; export JAVA_HOME
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64; export ORACLE_HOME
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and `PATH` has `JAVA_HOME` concatenated.

Any clue anybody?